# How to connect a 4D display to a beaglebone black?

Tags: display, beaglebone-black, beagleboard, beaglebone

I am fairly new to all this so sorry if this question is rather trivial.

I have a 4D Picasso Display (28PTU-Pi) and I want to connect it to my Beaglebone board. So plugged the usb cable into the board and the splash screen came up. But how do I connect it so that I can actually run programs on it like the tutorial?

On the homepage I could only find [this](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/productpages/4DPi-24-HAT/downloads/4DPi-24-HAT_datasheet_R_1_1.pdf), but that's for a Raspberry Pi and not Beaglebone.

Comment: I have successfully connected a [4DCAPE-43](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/4DCAPE_43/) to beaglebone black. From a time an effort standpoint this might be cheaper. But if you looking for hobby project (or real project for a customer), then this can be done. You need to weed through the 4D Picasso Display data sheet and map the I/O to BBB. Then you will have to make the necessary changes to BBB firmware

Comment: Glad things work out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done with [this](https://github.com/4dsystems/ViSi-Genie-RaspPi-Library) library and  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eYmtc3by3k) tutorial.

I copied all files onto the BBB then compiled the library, linked the libraries with the `calculator.c` program, changed the USB port to from `ttyAMA0` to `ttyUSB0` (in `calculator.c`) which is default I think for the BBB. and then run it and it worked.